# "Cef can only be initialized once" when registered js object

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp.WinForm 51.0.0.

When I added code registring js object after `Cef.Initialize(settings)`,

The exception occurs at runtime on `Cef.Initialize(settings)`.

> System.Exception was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233088
>   Message=Cef can only be initialized once. Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this exception.
>   Source=CefSharp.Core
>   StackTrace:
>           위치: CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(CefSettings cefSettings, Boolean shutdownOnProcessExit, Boolean performDependencyCheck)
>          위치: CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(CefSettings cefSettings)
>          위치: PcAppCef_WinForm.AppForm.InitializeChromium() 파일 d:\VisualStuidoRepo\StocktalkPC\PcAppCef_WinForm\AppForm.cs:줄 82
>          위치: PcAppCef_WinForm.AppForm..ctor() 파일 d:\VisualStuidoRepo\StocktalkPC\PcAppCef_WinForm\AppForm.cs:줄 53
>          위치: PcAppCef_WinForm.AppViewport..ctor() 파일 d:\VisualStuidoRepo\StocktalkPC\PcAppCef_WinForm\AppViewport.cs:줄 15
>          위치: PcAppCef_WinForm.AppForm.InitializeChromium() 파일 d:\VisualStuidoRepo\StocktalkPC\PcAppCef_WinForm\AppForm.cs:줄 90
>          위치: PcAppCef_WinForm.AppForm..ctor() 파일 d:\VisualStuidoRepo\StocktalkPC\PcAppCef_WinForm\AppForm.cs:줄 53
>          위치: PcAppCef_WinForm.Program.Main() 파일 d:\VisualStuidoRepo\StocktalkPC\PcAppCef_WinForm\Program.cs:줄 19

However, I just called `.RegisterJsObject()` method after `Cef.Initialize`
and when I removed(or commented) my code `chromeBrowser.RegisterJsObject` then works very well.

I don't understand why error occurs at `Initialize` method not `RegisterJsObject`.

This is my code.

```
 public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("*** Initializing Chromium");

            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();


            Cef.Initialize(settings);

            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(WebAppUrl);

            chromeBrowser.DownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler();
            chromeBrowser.MenuHandler = new ContextMenuHandler();
            //chromeBrowser.RequestHandler = new AppRequestHandler();

            // I want to a add js object but when I add this code, an error occurs on Cef.Initialize() as the blackquote above.
            chromeBrowser.RegisterJsObject("AppViewport", new AppViewport()); 


            this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }
```

Comment: Do you have a proper stack trace? Is that the only place your calling `Cef.Initialize`? What does `AppViewPort` do? You will need to provide code to reproduce the problem if you actually want it fixed. Or even better, grab the source and debug it for yourself.

Comment: I should also point out that you don't need to call `Cef.Initialize`, the constructor of `ChromiumWebBrowser` will do that for you https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/51/CefSharp.WinForms/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L279

Comment: @amaitland Thanks to comment again, I cannot edit the post because of "it looks like a sapm" message. When I removed `Cef.Initialize` the application not showing and error occured. 
And the error occured on `Cef.Initialize` on `InitializeChrome` method, right.

Comment: @amaitland I succeeded to update my stack trace, AppForm.cs : Line 82 is the code `Cef.initialize(settings)` above.

Comment: Maybe have a read over the stack trace again, it says you've called `InitializeChromium` twice and as the exception clearly says you can only call `Initialize` once, so you need to check `Cef.IsInitialized`. Add a break point in your code, should be pretty clear.

Comment: @amaitland Ah, I thought I didn't called again, I can remember that initializing a new object AppForm in AppViewport to get controls, sorry to bad asking,

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check initial before. I think it help you:

```
public void InitializeChromium()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("*** Initializing Chromium");

    if (!Cef.IsInitialized) // Check before init
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
    }

    chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(WebAppUrl);

    chromeBrowser.DownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler();
    chromeBrowser.MenuHandler = new ContextMenuHandler();
    //chromeBrowser.RequestHandler = new AppRequestHandler();

    // I want to a add js object but when I add this code, an error occurs on Cef.Initialize() as the blackquote above.
    chromeBrowser.RegisterJsObject("AppViewport", new AppViewport());


    this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
    chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

}
```